# Remote login from Web application using Node.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssh, remote-access

I have a remote machine that runs Ubuntu 14.04. It is powered on, but not logged into. I am writing a web application using Node.js that takes a username and password and logs in to this machine. This application is supposed to run on an Android tablet. I am not going to send further commands through the terminal, so I don't really require the session, but just logging in so that the remote machine starts running some processes.

I'm having trouble on how to start coding this. I'm not sure about what Node module to use, and whether or not to use the SSH protocol.

I've gone through a couple of solutions to related questions on the internet, but they either don't work on Android, or need the remote machine to be running some server already(which is not the case here, as the machine is not logged into).

Comment: Hey Jadadeesh, your question is pretty unclear. What exactly is it you're asking here?

Comment: Use SSH to login and run programs you want. This module can do that https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh-exec .